# Clearing the quickfix list in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to clear the Quickfix list in Vim since I want to get rid of highlighting and also if I accidently created a huge list I want to clean it up so vim becomes responsive again. Closing the window will not clear the list but the contents.

Comment: The QuickFix list shouldn't cause any slow downs. Also it does not highlight anything by default that I am aware of. Are you sure you don't have some plugin that is using the QuickFix window to highlight lines or using signs?

Comment: Yes I have plugins which do the highlight based on the quick fix, so with the default behaviour I see that there is no real reson to clear the window you are right.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only way I came up so far is

```
function ClearQuickfixList()
  call setqflist([])
endfunction
command! ClearQuickfixList call ClearQuickfixList()
nmap <leader>cf :ClearQuickfixList<cr>
```

EDIT (Thanks to Peter Rincker):

A better command is using `cexpr []` so the command is

```
command! ClearQuickfixList cexpr []
```

Comment: There is `:cexpr` as well. e.g. `:cexpr []` will clear the quickfix list. Your command would become `command! ClearQuickfixList cexpr []`

Comment: May I ask you how to remove a quickfix list from the `:chi`?

Comment: Note: with `:cexpr []` you're will create new list; with `:call setqflist([], 'r')` you're will replace current (clearing it)