# How do I search in all files of my project using VIM?

Tags: search, vim, neovim

There are a couple of things I do not yet understand the VIM way.

One of these is searching in a project like so (using VIM in Atom):

[image]

I use CtrlP currently for file names, but what about the contents?

How can I search with a string, and then look through a list of all occurrences using VIM and/or VIM plugins?

Comment: Install [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) and / or [ag](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/), and use the [CtrlSF](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) plugin.  You won't look back.

Comment: What is this vim distro / set-up / version / plugin? Looks awesome.

Comment: @AntonDaneyko That's [Atom](https://atom.io) with vim plugin.

Comment: just use telescope

Answer (score 104, accepted):

I've found an even better solution for this: [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)

It simply searches through everything in your project asynchronously using the `:Ag` command.

[image]

Comment: Note: this requires silver_searcher to be installed as well https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

Comment: For a less pretty solution that comes with VIM, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975174/how-do-i-search-the-open-buffers-in-vim

Comment: @Sem I installed silver_searcher, fzf  vim-plug package. Can you tell me how to do it...

Comment: @jian in your vim config add this line `nnoremap <C-s> :Ag<CR>`, this means call Ag whenever you press ctrl + s

Answer (score 41):

Use `:grep` or `:vimgrep` to search file contents. The results are put onto the "location list" which you can open by typing `:cw` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Syntax for `:grep` is, by default, the same as the [`grep(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) command:

```
:grep 'my pattern.*' /path/to/dir
```

By default it will search the current directory (`:pwd`). I added `set autochdir` to my .vimrc so my PWD always follows the file I'm editing.

The major difference between `:grep` and `:vimgrep` is that `:vimgrep` (`:vim` for short) uses Vim-compatible regular expressions, whereas `:grep` uses whatever regular expressions your `&grepprg` uses.

You can use a custom program by setting `&grepprg` to something different. I personally like [ack](https://github.com/petdance/ack2) which uses Perl-compatible regex.

Comment: Yes, and what about the list of occurrences?

Comment: @Sem I've expanded my answer to be as thorough as I can without getting too deep into it.

Comment: `:cw` is just what I need! You sir, are the best.

Comment: Hi. I find this super useful. I see I am able to navigate the list up and down. Is there any way to open a file directly by clicking `Enter` on the underlined file in the "location list"? I do a similar thing with NerdTree. Or maybe there is a "vimer" way to do this, hehe (still learning)

Comment: This is the slowest way.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from fzf, there are also other excellent plugins for fuzzy finding.

- [telescope.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) (neovim only): after install, just use `Telescope live_grep` to search through your project.
- [Leaderf](https://github.com/Yggdroot/LeaderF): another fuzzy finder with good performance. After install, use `Leaderf rg` to search through your project.

Answer (score 1):

To open a file, I highlight the row (Shift-v) in the location list and hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Neovim, a better solution is to use [telescope.nvim](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim) with [BurntSushi/ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) Suggested Dependencies you can use `live_grep` , `grep_string` and also `find_files`