# vim grep not finding anything

Tags: vim, grep

According to this documentation

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim

if grep is used like

```
:vim[grep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...
```

it should be able to find files by a matching pattern.

I have a text file named text.txt in the directory where I am starting vim from.

Content of text.txt is

```
look for me
```

In vim I enter the command

```
:grep /look/gj *.txt
```

but I don't get any results. Although the file text.txt contains the string "look".

[image: file content]
[image: current directory]

[image: pattern]
[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply confusing two commands: `:vimgrep` and `:grep`.

`:help :vimgrep` uses internal methods for searching files and has its own syntax and flags.

`:help :grep` uses an external program for searching so it doesn't have a defined syntax; the syntax you use is determined by what external program is used under the hood.

You can't really expect the `:vimgrep` syntax to work in `:grep`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using vim's syntax for grep instead of using `grep(1)` syntax.

As written here: [How do I search in all files of my project using VIM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398787/how-do-i-search-in-all-files-of-my-project-using-vim)

> Syntax for `:grep` is, by default, the same as the `grep(1)` command:
>
> `:grep 'my pattern.*' /path/to/dir`
>
> By default it will search the current directory (:pwd).
>
> The major difference between :grep and :vimgrep is that :vimgrep (:vim for >short) uses Vim-compatible regular expressions, whereas :grep uses whatever >regular expressions your &grepprg uses.

Answer (score 0):

The searches generally work in the current directory as well so I would check the output of `:pwd` and `:ls` to see if you are seeing what you expect to be seeing.

If you `:cd ~` however, you can search subdirectories with `vimgrep` by using `**` as the path:

```
:vim /look for me/ **/*.txt
```

I would also suggest that unless you have specific requirements, you do not use the `g` or `j` flags after the search pattern.